# Failed to connect to database error - R+RMySQL / XAMPP

Tags: mysql, r, xampp, rmysql

I am using a Mac. I successfully installed XAMPP. I also have installed RMySQL in R. I created a database in XAMPP. I now want to connect to this database in R. Assuming the database is called `name`, I have tried:

```
conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname='name')
```

I get this following error:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

What should I do? I am unsure of how to set up the user name, password, etc. Is there any source that describes the steps that need to be taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Grace's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699542/how-do-i-get-sql-database-into-r-from-local-host/24956219#24956219) worked for me. I ended up uninstalling XAMPP and installing MAMP. I created a database through MAMP+phpMyAdmin. Then, using the code of the answer by @Grace I was able to get it connected.